# Getting the value of readonly input in nested forms

Tags: php, html, forms

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
<form method="POST">
//something
<form method='GET'>
<input readonly type='text' id='userpwd' value= 'Day'  name='count'/>
<input type='submit' id='btn' formaction='admi.php'  name='admin' value='Add Details'></form>
<input type="submit" id="btn" formaction="choose.php"  name="admin" value="Done"></p>
</form>
```

I want to get the value of readonly type input in my new php file.How could I achieve this.I tried doing this:

```
$var=$_GET['count'];
```

but it is giving following  error msg:

```
Notice: Undefined index: count in C:\xampp\htdocs\tourism\admi.php on line 4
```

Please somebody help me out..!Kindly give some solution in php only.

Comment: `<form method="POST">
//something
<form method='GET'>` why 2 different methods? Also, does `$_POST['count']` give you the right value?

Comment: You should not nest forms. Can you provide more of the code?

Comment: I think that for readonly type input,only GET method works.Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `id`s should be unique, as should the `name` of each field, and probably best that they match. You can always use `type="hidden"` to store values in forms. As others have said, you shouldn't nest forms.

Comment: @TarishiJain `I think that for readonly type input,only GET method works`. There is no such thing. It works with POST too.

Comment: @taru ,form elements can never be nested.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form>` element shouldn't be nested:

> **4.10.3. The form element** 
>     Content model:
>     Flow content, but with **no form element descendants**.

[HTML 5.2 Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element)

Can't you do both forms seperate (not nested)?

---

**Edit:** If you need a `readonly` field to be sent in your form, you can add a hidden field with the same value :

```
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="Day" />
<input type="text" name="count" value="Day" readonly />
```

Comment: Nope,I'm working on some DBMS project and this nested thing will help me in further modules.

Comment: I edited my answer on "how to get readonly field".

Comment: Ok but it's not just a recommendation, I think the nested `<form>` will be ignored.

Comment: It isn't working.Still giving the same error.!

Comment: Because your `GET` form is being ignored. You can print both `var_dump($_GET);` and `var_dump($_POST);` to see their state.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['txtUserPwd'])) { echo "<div>" . $_GET['txtUserPwd'] . "</div>"; }
else { ?>
  <form method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="txtUserPwd" name="txtUserPwd" value="Day" readonly />
    <input type="submit" id="btnAdmi" name="btnAdmi" value="Add Details">
    <input type="button" id="btnChoose" name="btnChoose" value="Done">
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

This doesn't address your second button. I would do that with JavaScript or jQuery.